# AWS S3 bucket Vs Sharepoint Document Library

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, sharepoint, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS and exploring S3 bucket, I have requirement to move 1000s of sharepoint documents(exists in many document libraries) to move in AWS S3 and manage them same as in sharepoint.

Till now I created AWS S3 bucket and also add files/folders thru c# code found by googling, I also saw object tagging(upto 10 tags each for a file), versioning is available.

I am wondering, is AWS S3 has features like creating custom meta data columns as we do in sharepoint for a file (OR some other way to do this) and able to perform search files thru c# code? For example for Policy Document pdf files of client we store Name, ClientCode, Address, City, EMail etc in custom meta data columns and perform search.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html. And S3 .Net sdk code sample https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html

Comment: Awsome! I got it, we can add UserDefined meta data to files, but my question is, Can we quickly search all files by City eg: x-amz-meta-City=Sydney; as I dont know the filename or file path

Comment: Today, you cannot search on headers. There is a new feature called "Amazon S3 Select" that is in preview that will have more capabilities. I have not worked with it yet. Initially it looks like a simple SQL tool for searching contents of S3 files. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-s3-select-is-now-available-in-limited-preview/

Comment: How to migrate files from SharePoint to AWS S3 any reference?